# Git creates ssh keys in shared drive?

Tags: git

When I tried to create ssh keys for Git settings, it creates the keys in the shared drive while i try to do the same from c:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "harikumar@xyz.com"
```

Moreover, it always checks the host names and other setting from the shared drive.

It causes a lot of problem to commit when I don't have access to the share drive for some reasons

Any advice please to set everything in local drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates keys in `$HOME/.ssh`.

Make sure the environment variable `HOME` is set to the right path (*before* calling the git bash), and you won't have any issue.

Comment: Hi VonC, It is working now. Many thanks. Is there any way to set this path before starting git bash instead of setting environment variable HOME in windows ?

Comment: @Hari you need to set this path with HOME, but you can register HOME in the user environment variables of Windows, or in the .bashrc of your account in Linux.